# Catchphrases; Is it similar with colloquial expressions?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

Are [Catchphrases](http://id.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Catch+Phrase) only made by a certain group in a certain area? Do people live in Southern America have different catchphrases with those live in Northern America? 
May I count **dunno** and **wazz up** as catchphrases?

Comment: "dunno" and "wazz up" and even "wazaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" are hardly catchphrases. They are colloquial usages of "don't know" and "what is up?" respectively.

Answer (score 1):

**A catchphrase is usually created when a line said/written by someone is used very commonly by a group in their everyday conversations.** Catchphrases are phrases that *catch on* from one group of people to another. They are found in most languages and not just in English.

So a question asked by the *Joker* in The Dark Knight movie, "Why so serious?", might not have originally intended to be a catchphrase although you might have noticed people around you use it during conversations in light humour.

**"Dunno" and "Wazz up" on the other hand are not catchphrases. They are a part of the English slang word group and are used informally in different places.**